# How to put a custom VBA macro in a particular Excel cell?

Tags: excel, vba, cell

I have a custom defined VBA function called

Interpolate(ran As Range) As Double

which is added to a Formula Bar and is invoked for any given range of data, for example as

=Interpolate(B2:N2)

Now, I want to programmatically (in VBA) put this function into some cells, so it would automatically compute the interpolated values for the ranges to the left of the cell enabled with that macro. In my VBA code I am trying to do it in the following way:

Cells(row, column).Formula = "=Interpolate(B2:N2)"

and it works, however, I want the range to be dynamic, i.e. I don't know in advance how many columns will be to the left of the macro enabled cell. The function Interpolate() can handle any number of arguments (it interpolates in any N-dimensional space). So, I need to construct the Range argument of Interpolate() function dynamically, like this:

```
Private Function ColumnLetter(ColumnNumber As Long) As String
Dim n As Long
Dim c As Byte
Dim s As String

n = ColumnNumber
Do
    c = ((n - 1) Mod 26)
    s = Chr(c + 65) & s
    n = (n - c) \ 26
Loop While n > 0
ColumnLetter = s
End Function

Dim t1, t2, t3, t4, arg As String
t1 = "A"
t2 = t1 & CStr(row)
t3 = ColumnLetter(column - 1)
t4 = t3 & CStr(row)
arg = t2 & ":" & t4
Cells(row, column).Formula = "=Interpolate(arg)"
```

but this does not work. It works only when arg is specified explicitly and statically.

So, what to do?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you copied and pasted exactly your code but currently the formula would appear as:

> =Interpolate(arg)

Change it to:

```
"=Interpolate(" & arg & ")"
```

and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, what is happening is that arg is not being evaluated in your formula string. You'll need to expand it as follows:

```
Cells(row, column).Formula = "=Interpolate(" + arg + ")"
```

Anything within quotation marks are interpreted as a static string.